# GIT: Moving all content of a parent/subfolder to parent/

Tags: django, git, github, heroku, directory

I am new to Github. I have uploaded my Django app to Github that I will be using on Heroku.

I successfully added files and folders on the web interface of Github but realized that I incorrectly uploaded folders.

I cloned my github repo on my local machine. I have a sub-folder that I want to move to it's parent folder but the git mv is not working for me or I am doing something wrong I can't figure out what.

parent folder: PH_Dorms
sub folder: ph_dorms

1st try:

```
cd PH_Dorms
git mv ph_dorms ../
```

Result: fatal: '../' is outside repository

2nd try:

```
cd PH_Dorms
git mv ph_dorms ./
```

Result: "fatal: can not move directory into itself, source=ph_dorms, destination=ph_dorms

3rd try:

```
cd PH_Dorms
cd ph_dorms
git mv ph_dorms ./
```

Result: fatal: can not move directory into itself, source=ph_dorms/ph_dorms, destination=ph_dorms/ph_dorms

4th try:

```
cd PH_Dorms
cd ph_dorms
git mv ph_dorms ../
```

Result: fatal: cannot move directory over file, source=ph_dorms/ph_dorms, destination=ph_dorms

5th try:

```
cd PH_Dorms
cd ph_dorms
git mv ph_dorms/* ../
```

Result: fatal: bad source, source=ph_dorms/ph_dorms/*, destination=*

6th try:

```
cd PH_Dorms
cd ph_dorms
git mv * ../
```

Result: fatal: bad source, source=ph_dorms/*, destination=*

7th try:

```
cd PH_Dorms
cd ph_dorms
git mv * ./
```

Result: fatal: bad source, source=ph_dorms/*, destination=ph_dorms/*

I gave up! Never tried something else. Here's the screenshot from Git CMD:

[image]

If you need additional information, please let me know.

Comment: Try renaming the parent `PH_Dorms` to something else. Windows path names are case insensitive.

Comment: @BrahmaDev: I tried renaming the parent folder to another name and retried all options but still getting the same errors. By the way, I failed to mention that the PH_Dorms is the repository name on GitHub.

Comment: Show your entire directory please.... also, you could try: deleting the folder, uploading to github, recreating the folder (copy and paste from a bkp) and uploading again after adding to index

Comment: Also going by the error messages saying `bad source` I suspect `git mv` does not play with wildcards.

Comment: @Walucas: I finally worked on it by moving the folders around using Windows' File Explorer then do a git add, git commit and git push.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can gather your git repository's root only has one folder, ph_dorms, which has the rest of your project?

This should do the trick:

```
cd <path>/PH_Dorms
shopt -s dotglob
mv ph_dorms/* .
rmdir -p ph_dorms
git add --a
git commit -m '<message>'
git push
```

The above moves the content of ph_dorms into the root and safely deletes the ph_dorms folder. Then it adds your changes to GitHub.
To move filenames beginning with a dot `.` too in the current shell session, it necessary to run `shopt -s dotglob` first.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. What I did was use Window's File Explorer and move the folders and files around then did the following:
- git add .
- git commit -m 'moved to parent folder"
- git push

I didn't know it was this simple. :(

Answer (score 1):

> What I did was use Window's File Explorer and move the folders and files around

While that is working, know that your fourth try won't result in a misleading message anymore.

```bash
cd PH_Dorms
cd ph_dorms
git mv ph_dorms ../

fatal: cannot move directory over file, source=ph_dorms/ph_dorms, destination=ph_dorms
```

With Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), typofix in an error message.

See [commit c2cbefc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2cbefc51023a9d919846afb5629910d014d231c) (11 Aug 2023) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a59dbae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a59dbae0b3bdacfc7ebad40f784f38d6333e8608), 29 Aug 2023)</sup>

> ### [`mv`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2cbefc51023a9d919846afb5629910d014d231c): fix error for moving directory to another

> If both directories D1 and D2 already exists, and further there is a filesystem entity D2/D1, "[`git mv D1 D2`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c2cbefc51023a9d919846afb5629910d014d231c/Documentation/git-mv.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv))</sup> would fail, and we get an error message that says:
>
> ```
> "cannot move directory over file, source=D1, destination=D2/D1"
> ```
>
> regardless of the type of existing "`D2/D1`".
> If it is a file, the message is correct, but if it is a directory, it is not (we could make the `D2/D1` directory a union of its original contents and what was in `D1/`, but that is not what we do).
>
> The code that decides to issue the error message only checks for existence of "`D2/D1`" and does not care what kind of thing sits at the path.
>
> Rephrase the message to say:
>
> ```
> "destination already exists, source=D1, destination=D2/D1"
> ```
>
> that would be suitable for any kind of thing being in the way.

Comment: This happens even if `--force` is used, which is unfortunate.

Comment: @adam.hendry True. I do not know of a workaround for now.

Comment: FTM, on `bash`, prolly just `mv -f fldr/* . && git add -A`.